# Configuring multiple welcome pages in Seam

Tags: seam

I have a Seam application where the Login page is the default welcome page when the application is accessed. I have a few other pages for eg. Change password or Reset Password which donot require any authentication when they are accessed, as the user will fill in their details on those pages. But I cannot access these pages directly, for eg `http://localhost:8080/myProject/changePassword.seam` gives me a 403 error. Is there any configuration that I am missing?
My main concern is to show the Change Password page when a certain custom exception is thrown, which I will be handling in the `<exception>` tag in `pages.xml`. But when i put `<redirect view-id="/changePassword.seam">`, all I get is a blank page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure loginRequired on the page settings is set to false.  Also, redirects are usually specified as "/changePassword.xhtml".